# Cant get markers on google api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the `gem "geocoder"`  to get the lang and long from a address but I cant seem to be able to get a marker on my map

```
  - lat_long = Geocoder.coordinates(Mode.full_address).to_s.gsub('[', '').gsub(']', '')
  %script{:src => "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"}
  :javascript
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(#{lat_long})
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This places the map where it should be but it does not give me a marker

Answer (score 2):

Add a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker).

```
var map;

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(#{lat_long})
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    // Create a marker on map center
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```